# Why do browsers still allow Javascript to see cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm sure there's still plenty of sites out there that, for some inexplicable reason, use Javascript to manipulate cookies, but there's really no good reason to allow this in light of all the XSS that can occur.  Why do browsers still allow this?  Why not simply prevent JS from seeing cookies?

Comment: Because its a basic functionality. Use NoScript if that bothers you.

Comment: It's not about me, it's about users who get their cookies grabbed by XSS exploits in a gigantic unmaintainable codebase that we'd like to rebuild from scratch, but are prohibited from doing so. :)

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001167.html  HTTP Only cookies are cool...

Comment: @dirtside by that argument we should eliminate from every runtime  everything which could potentially hurt the user just to mitigate incompetent use of it.

Comment: Do you or do you ever intend to use Facebook Connect or a service like it? If yes, it would not be possible without JS <-> Cookie interaction.

Answer (score 6):

And lets be clear; JavaScript manipulating cookies is totally reasonable and acceptable. It, by itself, doesn't create an XSS issue. A badly written site does.

Answer (score 4):

I must admit, this question is similar to saying "Why do browsers still support HTML, its old". Backwards compatability is a huge issue, and cutting off all existing javascript code that manipulates cookies would be disastrous.

That being said, there are also cases where javascript manipulation of cookies is usefull for cross site communication and whatnot.

Answer (score 4):

This way you can set preferences directly in the cookies without making AJAX requests and save in the session / user_profile on the server side. This is useful for some UI preferences you want to keep when you revisited the website and on the server side its more easier because you don't need to register to see your preferences when your session has expired.

Comment: And how would you implement sessions without cookies? Using URL params? That's worse than cookies.

Comment: +1. A cookie with username=sean&password=1234 would just be stupid from the web developers standpoint.  But a cookie with hide_tips=true is harmless anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can set httponly cookies from the server side, and javascript can't see those. That would give the effect you desire.

I sometimes rely on cookies for storing a tiny amount of client-side data from javascript, understanding that this is suboptimal in that the browser will send the cookie in every request to the server even though it's only being used on the client side.

Comment: But not all browsers understand HTTPOnly cookies. And even if they understand, some of them have bugs.

Comment: Table of browser support / status of XMLHttpReponse hacks: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly#Browsers_Supporting_HTTPOnly

Still _BETTER_ than 100% of browsers giving up their cookies to a XSS attack.